# Windows 8 storage file

Tags: c#, file, windows-8

I have the following code

```
StorageFile sf = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("/data/elements.xml");
```

I'm trying to load the elements.xml file from the data folder within my project. I get the following error:

""Value does not fall within the expected range.""

I tried reversing the slashes and adding @ before the string. No luck.

Comment: Why are you using a leading slash? That creates an absolute path, not a relative one. Also, change your slashes to backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but if you want to use a path, use backslashes instead.

Answer (score 0):

If `elements.xml` is located in the Data folder, and the class file containing the code snippet below is located in a different folder say DataModel, use the string as shown should work for you.

```
var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("Data\\\elements.xml");
```